# Cannot install freeradius on ubuntu 16

Tags: 14.04, radius

I trying to install Freeradius on Ubuntu after I deleted it but it can not be installing  and showing this error:

```
netadmin@hotspot:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up freeradius-mysql (2.2.8+dfsg-0.1build2) ...
freeradius.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript freeradius, action "force-reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package freeradius-mysql (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 freeradius-mysql
```

And this error when trying to install:

```
Job for freeradius.service failed because the control process exited with error                                                                                                              code. See "systemctl status freeradius.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details                                                                                                             .
invoke-rc.d: initscript freeradius, action "restart" failed.
● freeradius.service - LSB: Radius Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/freeradius; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-06-02 10:19:33 -03; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14610 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/freeradius start (code=exited, status=1/F                                                                                                             AILURE)
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Radius Daemon...
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot freeradius[14610]:  * Starting FreeRADIUS daemon fre...s
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot freeradius[14610]:    ...fail!
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Control process exi...=1
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Radius Daemon.
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Unit entered failed...e.
Jun 02 10:19:33 hotspot systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Failed with result ...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I tried all things to be sure that the old Freeradius is completely removed 
but cannot install new